# Html Css Remove distance between images and p

Tags: html, css

I am wondering how to remove a distance in this case between images and p. The picture which shows what I am talking about:

[image: what I want]

The code looks like this:

```css
html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    header { position: relative;  z-index: 1;}
    
    /*#images-fs {*/
    /*  z-index: -10;*/
    /*}*/
    
    #wrapper {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      top: 0; left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: -1;
      background: forestgreen;
    }
    
    #content {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      position: absolute;
      padding: 0;
      margin-left: 0;
      margin-right: 0;
      text-align:center;
      overflow: auto;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 70px;
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 25px;
    }
    
    p {
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    body {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    div.box {
    
      margin: 0 auto;
      font-size: 0;
      width: 875px;
      --R:175px; /* radius */
      --m:5px;   /* margin */
      --t:50px;  /* distance from top */
    }
    
    p {
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    div.box p {
      width: 50%;
      margin:0;
      padding:0 var(--m);
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align:top;
      text-align: justify;
    }
    
    div.box p:before {
      content: "";
      width: var(--R);
      height: calc(2*var(--R));
      margin-top:var(--t);
      shape-outside: circle(var(--R) at var(--d,right) calc(-1*var(--m)) top calc(50% + var(--t)/2));
      float: right;
      margin-right:calc(-1*var(--m));
    }
    
    div.box p:last-child:before {
      float: left;
      padding:0 0;
      --d:left;
      background-position:right;
      margin-left:calc(-1*var(--m));
      margin-right:0;
    }
    
    *,*::before,*::after {
      box-sizing:border-box;
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    .tooltip {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      margin-top:50px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .tooltip .tooltiptext {
      visibility: hidden;
      width: 120px;
      background-color: black;
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 6px;
      padding: 5px 0;
      z-index: 1;
      margin: 0;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      font-size:20px;
    }
    
    .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
      visibility: visible;
    }
```

```html
 <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="content">
        <br><br>
    
        <div class="box">
          <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
          <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            <br><br>
          </p>
    
          <div class="tooltip">
            <img src="https://jakuwegiel.web.app/assets/images/DSC_0925a-1.png" width="350px" height="350px">
            <span class="tooltiptext">My beautiful face</span>
          </div>
    
    
    
          <div class="tooltip">
            <img src="https://jakuwegiel.web.app/assets/images/cards.png" width="350px" height="350px">
          </div>
          <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
    
        <br><br><br>
        Programming is my hobby and <b>I love it</b>! :)
        <br><br>
      </div>
    </div>
```

If you need to see on codepen just take a look in [here](https://codepen.io/Kiubaz/pen/VwKdGOe?editors=1100). I do not know what else I need to add. I wrote everythink you need.

If you add valuable answer for me, I will mark as best one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the paragraphs on the left a `class="left-aligned"`, and give the paragraphs on the right a `class="right-aligned"`.

Add the following rules to your CSS:

```css
p {
  position: relative;
}

.left-aligned {
  right: -150px;
}

.right-aligned {
  left: -150px;
}
```

You can change the value `150px` to any value that you prefer (as long as it is negative).

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  background: forestgreen;
}

#content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 25px;
}

p {
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.left-aligned {
  right: -150px;
}

.right-aligned {
  left: -150px;
}

div.box {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 0;
  width: 875px;
  --R: 175px;
  /* radius */
  --m: 5px;
  /* margin */
  --t: 50px;
  /* distance from top */
}

div.box p {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 var(--m);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: justify;
}

div.box p:before {
  content: "";
  width: var(--R);
  height: calc(2 * var(--R));
  margin-top: var(--t);
  shape-outside: circle( var(--R) at var(--d, right) calc(-1 * var(--m)) top calc(50% + var(--t) / 2));
  float: right;
  margin-right: calc(-1 * var(--m));
}

div.box p:last-child:before {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 0;
  --d: left;
  background-position: right;
  margin-left: calc(-1 * var(--m));
  margin-right: 0;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 20px;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content" [ngStyle]="{'bottom': footerHeight + 10 + 'px'}">
    <app-text-effect [input]="'About'"></app-text-effect>
    <br><br>

    <div class="box">
      <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
      <p class="left-aligned">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        <br><br>
      </p>

      <div class="tooltip">
        <img src="https://jakuwegiel.web.app/assets/images/DSC_0925a-1.png" width="350px" height="350px">
        <span class="tooltiptext">My beautiful face</span>
      </div>

      <div class="tooltip">
        <img src="https://jakuwegiel.web.app/assets/images/cards.png" width="350px" height="350px">
      </div>
      <p class="right-aligned">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </p>
    </div>

    <br><br><br> Programming is my hobby and <b>I love it</b>! :)
    <br><br>
  </div>
</div>
```